# C++ non blocking socket select send too slow?

Tags: c++, sockets, select, send, nonblocking

I have a program that maintains a list of "streaming" sockets. These sockets are configured to be non-blocking sockets.

Currently, I have used a list to store these streaming sockets. I have some data that I need to send to all these streaming sockets hence I used the iterator to loop through this list of streaming sockets and calling the send_TCP_NB function below:

The issue is that my own program buffer that stores the data before sending to this send_TCP_NB function slowly decreases in free size indicating that the send is slower than the rate at which data is put into the program buffer. The rate at which the program buffer is about 1000 data per second. Each data is quite small, about 100 bytes.

Hence, i am not sure if my send_TCP_NB function is working efficiently or correct?

```
int send_TCP_NB(int cs, char data[], int data_length) {

    bool sent = false;
    FD_ZERO(&write_flags);      // initialize the writer socket set
    FD_SET(cs, &write_flags);   // set the write notification for the socket based on the current state of the buffer
    int status;
    int err;

    struct timeval waitd;       // set the time limit for waiting
    waitd.tv_sec = 0;
    waitd.tv_usec = 1000;

    err = select(cs+1, NULL, &write_flags, NULL, &waitd);
    if(err==0)
    {
        // time limit expired
        printf("Time limit expired!\n");
        return 0;   // send failed
    }
    else
    {
        while(!sent)
        {
                if(FD_ISSET(cs, &write_flags))
                {
                     FD_CLR(cs, &write_flags);
                     status = send(cs, data, data_length, 0);
                     sent = true;
                }
         }

         int nError = WSAGetLastError();
         if(nError != WSAEWOULDBLOCK && nError != 0)
         {      
              printf("Error sending non blocking data\n");
              return 0;
         }
         else
         {
              if(nError == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
              {
                    printf("%d\n", nError);
              }
              return 1;
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: A small unrelated point, you should only check `WSAGetLastError` if the return from `send` is `SOCKET_ERROR`. Also, `send` may not be able to send all data at once, so call it in a loop (with increasing data pointer and decreasing size) until all is sent. Also, there is really no need for the `select` call, but it _do_ tell you if you can send _at least_ one byte without blocking. And there is no need for your loop around the send, if the socket is not in `write_flags` after `select`, you will loop forever.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg good point on the fact that send may not be able to send everything in one time, I missed it.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that would help is if you thought out *exactly* what this function is supposed to do. What it actually does is probably not what you wanted, and has some bad features.

The major features of what it does that I've noticed are:

1. Modify some global state
2. Wait (up to 1 millisecond) for the write buffer to have some empty space
3. Abort if the buffer is still full
4. Send 1 or more bytes on the socket (ignoring how much was sent)
5. If there was an error (including the send decided it would have blocked despite the earlier check), obtain its value. Otherwise, obtain a random error value
6. Possibly print something to screen, depending on the value obtained
7. Return 0 or 1, depending on the error value.

Comments on these points:

1. Why is `write_flags` global?
2. Did you *really* intend to block in this function?
3. This is probably fine
4. Surely you care *how much* of the data was sent?
5. I do not see anything in the documentation that suggests that this will be zero if `send` succeeds

If you cleared up what the actual intent of this function was, it would probably be much easier to ensure that this function actually fulfills that intent.

That said

> I have some data that I need to send to all these streaming sockets

What *precisely* is your need?

If your need is that the data must be sent before proceeding, then using a non-blocking write is inappropriate*, since you're going to have to wait until you can write the data anyways.

If your need is that the data must be sent sometime in the future, then your solution is missing a very critical piece: you need to create a buffer for each socket which holds the data that needs to be sent, and then you periodically need to invoke a function that checks the sockets to try writing whatever it can. If you spawn a new thread for this latter purpose, this is the sort of thing `select` is very useful for, since you can make that new thread block until it is able to write something. However, if you don't spawn a new thread and just periodically invoke a function from the main thread to check, then you don't need to bother. (just write what you can to everything, even if it's zero bytes)

*: At least, it is a very premature optimization. There are some edge cases where you could get slightly more performance by using the non-blocking writes intelligently, but if you don't understand what those edge cases are and how the non-blocking writes would help, then guessing at it is unlikely to get good results.

EDIT: as another answer implied, this is something the operating system is good at anyways. Rather than try to write your own code to manage this, if you find your socket buffers filling up, then make the system buffers larger. And if they're *still* filling up, you should *really* give serious thought to the idea that your program needs to block anyways, so that it stops sending data faster than the other end can handle it. i.e. just use ordinary blocking `send`s for all of your data.

Comment: +1 It is true that the original code is losing its aim along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Some general advice:

- Keep in mind you are multiplying data. So if you get 1 MB/s in, you output N MB/s with N clients. Are you sure your network card can take it ? It gets worse with smaller packets, you get more general overhead. You may want to consider broadcasting.
- You are using non blocking sockets, but you block while they are not free. If you want to be non blocking, better discard the packet immediately if the socket is not ready.
- What would be better is to "select" more than one socket at once. Do everything that you are doing but for all the sockets that are available. You'll write to each "ready" socket, then repeat again while there are sockets that are not ready. This way, you'll proceed with the sockets that are available first, and then with some chance, the busy sockets will become themselves available.
- the `while (!sent)` loop is useless and probably buggy. Since you are checking only one socket `FD_ISSET` will always be true. It is wrong to check again `FD_ISSET` after a `FD_CLR`
- Keep in mind that your OS has some internal buffers for the sockets and that there are way to extend them (not easy on Linux, though, to get large values you need to do some config as root).
- There are some socket libraries that will probably work better than what you can implement in a reasonable time (`boost::asio` and `zmq` for the ones I know).
- If you need to implement it yourself, (i.e. because for instance zmq has its own packet format), consider using a threadpool library.

### EDIT:

- Sleeping 1 millisecond is probably a bad idea. Your thread will probably get descheduled and it will take much more than that before you get some CPU time again.

Comment: I have tried on 127.0.0.1 so that should take the load off the network card? Regarding broadcasting, is it possible to do with TCP because I thought this technique is more for UDP.

Comment: Yes for the load. No it is not possible with TCP, though, UDP is sometimes a good choice. Especially if you drop packets from time to time in your code. Note that there are reliable multicast implementations (like PGM and EPGM). They do not loose packets as easily as UDP.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a horrible way to do things. The `select` serves no purpose but to waste time. If the `send` is non-blocking, it can mangle data on a partial send. If it's blocking, you still waste arbitrarily much time waiting for one receiver.

You need to pick a sensible I/O strategy. Here is one: Set all sockets non-blocking. When you need to send data to a socket, just call `write`. If all the data writes, lovely. If not, save the portion of data that wasn't sent for later and add the socket to your write set. When you have nothing else to do, call `select`. If you get a hit on any socket in your write set, write as many bytes as you can from what you saved. If you write all of them, remove that socket from the write set.

(If you need to write to a data that's already in your write set, just add the data to the saved data to be sent. You may need to close the connection if too much data gets buffered.)

A better idea might be to use a library that already does all these things. Boost::asio is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `select()` before calling `send()`.  Do it the other way around.  Call `select()` only if `send()` reports `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, eg:

```
int send_TCP_NB(int cs, char data[], int data_length)
{ 
    int status; 
    int err; 
    struct timeval waitd;

    char *data_ptr = data;
    while (data_length > 0)
    {
        status = send(cs, data_ptr, data_length, 0); 
        if (status > 0)
        {
            data_ptr += status;
            data_length -= status;
            continue;
        }

        err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (err != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            printf("Error sending non blocking data\n"); 
            return 0;   // send failed 
        }

        FD_ZERO(&write_flags);
        FD_SET(cs, &write_flags);   // set the write notification for the socket based on the current state of the buffer 

        waitd.tv_sec = 0; 
        waitd.tv_usec = 1000; 

        status = select(cs+1, NULL, &write_flags, NULL, &waitd); 
        if (status > 0) 
            continue;

        if (status == 0)
            printf("Time limit expired!\n"); 
        else
            printf("Error waiting for time limit!\n"); 

        return 0;   // send failed 
    }

    return 1; 
}
```